# Submission Failed (Swift Playgrounds 4)

Tags: swift, upload, app-store-connect, swift-playground

I am trying to upload my app from swift Playgrounds to App Store Connect, however I get this error Message.. Anyone seen this before?

“ The operation couldn't be completed.
(Playgrounds.ProjectDocument.
(unknown context at $1031b739c).
(unknown context at $103167560).
(unknown context at
$1031b7568).BuildFailure error 1.) “

I have uploaded many apps from playgrounds before without any issue.

Comment: I’m getting this too. — I haven’t tried uploading before, though.

Comment: If makes no sense, I tried coping my code to a new project, and it worked, however few days later i got the same error..

Comment: I ended up finding an app I could use to push the code to GitHub, and then submitting it from Xcode. (13 can open the .swiftpm playgrounds projects)